# PHP PayPal Payment Method

Tags: php, paypal

Could someone guide me how to create a withdraw fund page using PayPal...

I want to create one PHP page (interface) contains a button "Withdraw" and 2 textboxes, one for my customer paypal e-mail and the other to put the amount of money they want to withdraw. When they click the "Withdraw" button, without any redirect to the PayPal site, **if POSSIBLE**, my website will transfer the amount of money from their account to the client account.

I don't know what method should I use, and since there are no integration wizard yet for payment. It's become difficult for a newbie like me. Here are the important points of my problem:

1. What's the BEST payment method to use? Adaptive, MassPay, or any others?
   (But I believe it won't be a payment pro like express checkout ;D)
2. Could you give me the tutorial (step-by-step) how to use/make it, if any?
3. Are there any way to achieve a payment system without a need to redirect out from my site and go to paypal first?

Thanks~!

Answer (score 0):

See the manual here for more information [PayPal Documentation](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/documentation)

You can use api without redirecting. but you will need more than an email address to move funds.